# Kendo UI Bootstrap theme not working well with Bootstrap 3.1.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm just in the process of converting a site based on Bootstrap 2.3 to 3.1 and I've got lots of issues with Kendo's Bootstrap theme.

I tend to use use Bootstrap form-groups within custom Grid popup editors, but they don't behave with Kendo's CSS.

I've setup a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/ZPuS8/4/) to show the problem. As you can see when you edit a record, the sizing and positioning of the labels and input and way out.

It's something to do with the last two entries in the `common-template.less` file:

```
.k-animation-container,
.k-widget,
.k-widget *,
.k-animation-container *,
.k-widget *:before,
.k-animation-container *:after
{
    .box-sizing(content-box);
}

.k-button,
.k-textbox,
.k-autocomplete,
div.k-window-content,
.k-tabstrip > .k-content > .km-scroll-container,
.k-block,
.k-edit-cell .k-widget,
.k-grid-edit-row .k-widget,
.k-grid-edit-row .text-box,
.km-actionsheet > li,
.km-shim
{
    .box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

If you remove these the Bootstrap forms look correct, but certain Kendo elements (such as the pager) are adversely affected.

Is there a way around this or is this not how Telerik intend for its framework to be used?

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using the below CSS styles to get Bootstrap elements to look right inside of Kendo elements. We especially had problems getting `.row` (and column classes) to work inside Kendo Windows, but this CSS fixed our issues.

```
.k-widget select, .k-widget textarea, .k-widget input[type="text"]:not(.k-input), .k-widget input[type="password"], .k-widget input[type="datetime"], .k-widget input[type="datetime-local"], .k-widget input[type="date"], .k-widget input[type="month"], .k-widget input[type="time"], .k-widget input[type="week"], .k-widget input[type="number"], .k-widget input[type="email"], .k-widget input[type="url"], .k-widget input[type="search"], .k-widget input[type="tel"], .k-widget input[type="color"], .k-widget .uneditable-input {
    box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.k-window .row, .k-window .row *:not(.k-widget):not(.k-animation-container), .k-widget .row *:before:not(.k-widget) { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

.k-widget .col-lg-1, .k-widget .col-lg-2, .k-widget .col-lg-3, .k-widget .col-lg-4, .k-widget .col-lg-5, .k-widget .col-lg-6, .k-widget .col-lg-7, .k-widget .col-lg-8, .k-widget .col-lg-9, .k-widget .col-lg-10, .k-widget .col-lg-11, .k-widget .col-lg-12, .k-widget .col-md-1, .k-widget .col-md-2, .k-widget .col-md-3, .k-widget .col-md-4, .k-widget .col-md-5, .k-widget .col-md-6, .k-widget .col-md-7, .k-widget .col-md-8, .k-widget .col-md-9, .k-widget .col-md-10, .k-widget .col-md-11, .k-widget .col-md-12, .k-widget .col-sm-1, .k-widget .col-sm-2, .k-widget .col-sm-3, .k-widget .col-sm-4, .k-widget .col-sm-5, .k-widget .col-sm-6, .k-widget .col-sm-7, .k-widget .col-sm-8, .k-widget .col-sm-9, .k-widget .col-sm-10, .k-widget .col-sm-11, .k-widget .col-sm-12, .k-widget .col-xs-1, .k-widget .col-xs-2, .k-widget .col-xs-3, .k-widget .col-xs-4, .k-widget .col-xs-5, .k-widget .col-xs-6, .k-widget .col-xs-7, .k-widget .col-xs-8, .k-widget .col-xs-9, .k-widget .col-xs-10, .k-widget .col-xs-11, .k-widget .col-xs-12
{
    box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From Kendo docs:

> Kendo UI uses the default content-box box model (box-sizing CSS
>   property), while Bootstrap uses the non-default bordex-box model and
>   applies it to all elements on the page, including ones that are
>   unrelated to Bootstrap. 
>   ......
>   A possible easy workaround is to
>   override the Bootstrap CSS, apply content-box box model to all
>   elements on the page and use a border-box box model only to selected
>   Bootstrap elements, which need it (these are all .col-... classes,
>   .row, .container and .container-fluid). You can add the following CSS
>   rules after the Bootstrap and Kendo UI stylesheets.

See reference for sample css solution:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nesting-kendo-ui-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout

Comment: I love how Kendo tries to spin the situation by calling `content-box` box sizing the "default" model. While it may be default, simply because it is the old-fashioned model, it is neither best nor easy to use, compared to `border-box`. Bootstrap made a great move by using the newer, better model and will hopefully move everyone toward the `border-box` model, instead of making excuses, as Kendo has done.

Comment: Kendo's suggested fix from the linked page worked great for me.  I have no idea why I'm surprised, but, yeah.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JohnWasham That is such a short sighted statement. It wasn't that long ago that everyone referred to the `border-box` model as the **Internet Explorer box model bug**. Everyone thought the `content-box` model was the master race. The `border-box` model was widely used before `content-box`.

Comment: @surfasb, what you wrote is true, but I'm not sure how it conflicts with what I wrote. The point was that Telerik shouldn't act as if `content-box` is the best choice, simply because it's "default."

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding those css lines... :

```
.k-animation-container, .k-widget, .k-widget *, .k-animation-container *, .k-widget *:before, .k-animation-container *:after, .k-block .k-header, .k-list-container {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.k-block > .k-header, .k-window-titlebar {
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This definitely has to do with the fact Bootstrap and Kendo rely on different box models and the difficulties in making elements that rely on `box-sizing: border-box` intermix with those that rely on `box-sizing: content-box`.

In general, all the styling for Kendo is based on the standard `content-box` model. However, all the styling for Bootstrap relies on the easier to use `border-box` model. The biggest difference between the two is how padding, borders, etc. are treated. In `content-box` they're part of the width of an element, in `border-box` they're not.

Bootstrap assumes that of course you want to use `border-box`, and why wouldn't you! It helpfully sets *everything on the page* to use `border-box`, including the Kendo widgets. For it's part, Kendo knows that Bootstrap might set everything to use `border-box` so it sets everything back to `content-box` for Kendo widgets and *all their children*. So now if you nest anything Bootstrap related inside anything Kendo related you'll get the wrong box model. It's a mess.

I've tried a bunch of different hacks to try and mitigate this, but the fact of the matter is there's no good way to resolve it. This is the CSS code that I have found works best so far (it uses a CSS attribute selector, so it's a no-go for older browsers):

```
.border-box, .border-box * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    [class^="k-"] {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
}
```

Then you set `class='border-box'` on any element that might get nested inside of a Kendo widget that you know will have Bootstrap content.